# Lista com grande quantidade de itens, consumo excessivo da memória

Tags: c#, winforms, lista

No meu sistema tenho uma `List<object>`, durante a utilização do sistema vou adicionando itens nela ate chegar em um certo ponto que o sistema começa a travar, a ficar muito lento. Meu sistema pode chegar a adicionar até quarenta mil itens nessa lista, nunca cheguei a esse ponto, pois trava antes.

O que poderia ser feito nessa situação?

Obs: não gostaria de ter que utilizar um BD

Comment: Olha cara são muitos itens e é provável o travamento, O ideal é utilizar um BD que é adequado para receber grandes dados, Eu até entendo que você não queira utilizar DB porem não podemos trocar gato por lebre né? ... Eu recomendaria um DB interno sem conexão externa e tal, apenas para salvar os itens.

Comment: Adicione na pergunta um trecho de código que demonstre como essa lista está sendo criada, da maneira que a pergunta está fica difícil desenvolver uma solução.

Comment: Nem um BD local como SQL Compact ou SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

Se você sabe que ele adiciona até 40 mil itens, é recomendado colocar um limite nessa lista, para que você tenha um ganho de performance descrito [nesse link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176916/adding-to-listt-becomes-very-slow-over-time)

> Toda hora que você adiciona um elemento na lista, e se a lista estiver
> com sua alocação em memória cheia, um novo bloco de memoria é
> utilizado com o dobro do tamanho atual, e copia tudo para esse
> bloco(queda de performance) e continua adicionando os elementos novos
> até que a lista fique cheia e o processo se repete.

Então utilize:

```
List<object> lista = new List<object>(40000);
```

**OUTRO POSSIVEL PROBLEMA:**

*Caso for possivel, instancie a lista com tipo definido, e não "object", porem não sei se tem algum ganho de performance.*

Answer (score 0):

Cara Se você não quer Usar um BD Pode tentar uma abordagem do tipo serializar sua lista em pequenos blocos em formato Xml ou Stream Mesmo, e armazenar em disco de forma Organizada criando um sistema de busca e manutenção desses dados. Ou usar um banco local do tipo sqlite que é exatamente isso que ele vai fazer. Porque de qualquer forma se um objeto seu usar 20kb de memoria multiplicado pelo total da lista é o que ele ira consumir e não vai sair da memoria porque você mantem ela em uso.